# RSPEC : replacing session with cookies in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Initially my controller was using session to store a variable

```
session["quiz_intro"] = 'true'
```

Now I have replaced session with cookies like this

```
cookies["quiz_intro"] = 'true'
```

The controller keeps working as it is supposed to but the specs I have written fail.
My specs when I was using session variable were like this

```
request.session["quiz_intro"] = 'true'
```

Now the specs look like this

```
request.cookies["quiz_intro"] = 'true'
```

I cannot figure out why my specs are failing. Is thr anything else that I should do in specs when using cookies?
I am using rails3 and rspec-rails 2.6.1